# toolchains for cross-compilation of 32bit ARMv7-a platform

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, cross-compiling, gnu-toolchain

I need to cross compile a C++ project for a `32bit` `ARMv7-a` target platform. Could someone please let me know where from it would be possible to download toolchains for this cross compilation?

So far, there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25014516/5821185) information available, but would it be sufficient?

I am using 6.1.31-2-MANJARO x86_64 Linux.

Comment: *platform*; what does this mean?  What is your target (on the machine where the code will run) OS and libc.  These are also important to an answer.  But mainly, stackoverflow does not recommend lists of things as they will quickly go out of date.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I used the Linaro toolchain: https://www.linaro.org/downloads/

It is also one available from arm: https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/arm-gnu-toolchain-downloads

Comment: May I ask how to cross compile projects wit ```sys/socket.h``` dependency or other host OS dependency? What I see in the second link you provided is ```x86_64 Linux hosted cross toolchains AArch32 bare-metal target (arm-none-eabi)``` ?

Comment: Yes the provided Links are only for bare-metal cross-compilations. Depending on your hardware you have to use `...-eabi` or `...-gnueabihf`. If you wanna cross-compile an application executed on a Linux OS on the target platform, you may use the SDK provided from the board manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I could find the toolchains needed from what you've suggested.

Comment: The linaro toolchains are supporting arm-linux.  As the ARM links say, these are discontinued.  Only gcc v10 is found.  crosstool-ng is a toolsuite to build your own compiler.  It is used by Ubuntu and launchpad/linaro to build the compilers.